# Questions concerning quotient ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(XY-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Hi I'm making some practice exam questions of my introductory course of algebra.
I came across the following exercise concerning the ring $R=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]}{XY-1}$.

1. Is $(\overline{1-X})$ a unit?
2. Is $(\overline{X})$ a maximal ideal?
3. Prove $R$ is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}[X,\frac{1}{X}]$.
4. Determine the field of fractions of R

I honestly don't have much of a clue on how to get started.I can see that for the second question it's not a maximal ideal since the ideal is the whole ring due to the fact that $\overline{X}$ is a unit with $\overline{Y}$ as it's inverse. For the first I can't intuitively find its inverse but I have no idea how to prove it. As for the other exercises I don't know how to get started on them so maybe a small hint would really help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning for $(2)$ is correct. $(\overline{X})=R$ is non maximal.

For $3$ - hint: the defining property of $1/X$ is that $X(1/X)-1=0$.

For $4$ - once you know $R\cong\Bbb Z[X,X^{-1}]$, observe that "$X$" already has an inverse in $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ so it remains to think about $\mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb Z[X])$.

For $1$, this is a polynomial division exercise. Does there exist two polynomials $f(X,Y),g(X,Y)$ such that $f(X,Y)(1-X)=1+g(X,Y)(XY-1)$? Or, if you've done $(3)$, can $h(X,X^{-1})(1-X)=1$? There is a fancier method, which is to find a way to justify:

> "$(1-X)^{-1}=1+X+X^2+\cdots$ is not a polynomial"

Comment: There are easier (imo) approaches to 1. For example, it suffices to show that $R/(1-\overline{X}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(XY-1,1-X)$ is not the zero ring, and for this it suffices to define a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y] \to \mathbb{Z}$ whose kernel contains $(XY-1,1-X)$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think the map $\Bbb Z[X,Y]\to\Bbb Z$ associated to "sum of all coefficients" does the trick. That's nice

Comment: Indeed, and this is in fact the unique homomorphism which works :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a zero homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y] \to \mathbb{Z}$ -- ring homomorphisms must send $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$.

Comment: oh true, I was thinking in terms of groups

Comment: @diracdeltafunk isn't it a field homomorphism that sends 1 to 1? Or is it because $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ is a ring with $1$ such that a ring homomorphism is either the zero projection or $f(1)=1$?

Comment: @FShrike for 3 I could then just use the first isomorphism theorem? With the homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]\to \mathbb{Z}[X,1/X]: \phi(f(X,Y))=f(X,1/X)$ such that the kernel is $(XY-1)$ and then prove surjectivity?

Comment: @rikdb the first isomorphism theorem is your friend here, and that’s correct. Make sure you can argue carefully why the kernel is exactly $(XY-1)$ and not any larger

Comment: I'm not quite sure about how to start with that. Like consider a function in the kernel so a function such that $f(X,1/X)=0$ and prove the function $f(X,Y) \in (XY-1)$. Does it help to explicitly describe the polynomial?

Comment: @rikdb $f(X,1/X)=0$ gives you a lot of information about the coefficients of $f$, which terms can be nonzero, what the degrees of each monomial are. Alternatively identify $\Bbb Z[X,Y]/(XY-1)\cong\Bbb Z[X][Y]/(XY-1)$; now the problem is the more general one - is $R[Y]/(r\cdot Y-1)\cong R[r^{-1}]$ (for a commutative ring $R$. If $R$ is not a domain then $R[r^{-1}]$ is a bit funny but still makes sense)

Comment: With the coefficients of $f$ then the only ones which can be nonzero are the for which $X$ and $1/X$ or $X$ and $Y$ have the same degree.

Comment: @rikdb Great, agreed. So $f(X,Y)=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n X^nY^n$ for some integers $a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_N$. But also $f(X,1/X)=0$ tells you something extra about the $a_n$; I suggest you also think about what $XY=1$ in $R$ tells you about $X^nY^n$.

Comment: okay so $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n =0$ then since $f(X,1/X)=0$ but on the second I don't think I understand. Do you just mean that $X^nY^n=1$ or am I wrong?

Comment: @rikdb Yes, that’s why I mean. So in $R$, $f(X,Y)=\sum_{n=0}^Na_nX^nY^n=\sum_{n=0}^Na_n(1)=\sum_{n=0}^Na_n=0$… as desired. You can explicitly factorise: $$\Bbb Z[X,Y]\ni f(X,Y)=(XY-1)\left(a_0+\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\cdot(1+XY+X^2Y^2+\cdots+X^{n-1}Y^{n-1})\right)\in(XY-1)$$By way of a polynomial division but it’s conceptually cleaner to work in $R$. Remember for the first isomorphism to work you just need to show $f(X,1/X)=0\implies f=0\text{ in $R$}$

Comment: okay, got it. thank you very much